# Share variables between R and Python in jupyternotebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, python-3.6, rpy2

How to pass the R variable to Python?

In jupyternotebook, I'm using `%reload_ext rpy2.ipython` to use R and Python in one note. I know how to pass python variable to R by using
`%%R -i xxx` to pass a python variable xxx to R in the cell, but how to pass a R variable back to python? It's it possible technically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following Jupyter magic code demonstrates the use of `R` to compute 1+2+3 and save the result in variable `rvar`, then pass it to Python. The option `-o rvar` specifies that the variable `rvar` is required as `output` to Python environment.

```
%R -o rvar rvar=1+2+3
```

On another cell, you can use Python to manipulate that variable:

```
print(rvar)      # [1] 6
print(rvar[0])   # 6.0
```

For more complex example, with multiple output variables:

```
%%R -o X -o sdx -o xbar
X=c(1,4,5,7);
sdx=sd(X);
xbar=mean(X)
```

In (Python) Jupyter notebook, you get `X`, `sdx`, and `xbar` as the output. You can check them by running the code:

```
print('X:', X)
print('X[1]:', X[1])
print('sdx:', sdx)
print('xbar:', xbar)
```

More information about `R magic` can be found [here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/config/extensions/rmagic.html).

Alternatively, you can use `%Rpull` and `%Rget` to get object from `rpy2`.

**Edit**

[Updated reference link](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.0.x/html/interactive.html#module-rpy2.ipython.rmagic)
as hinted by @lgautier in the comment.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, and I'm wondering where did you see these instructions about this? And how should I output multiple variables in one block? Thanks for your patience

Comment: @swatchai: that documentation is long outdated, as the "R magic" moved out of the ipython code base. You might want use https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.0.x/html/interactive.html#module-rpy2.ipython.rmagic as your reference documentation instead.

Comment: is it possible to do the reverse ? using Python variables in R ?

Comment: @ShidharthRouth  Objects can be passed back and forth between rpy2 and python via the -i -o flags in line. See https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.0.x/html/interactive.html#module-rpy2.ipython.rmagic for examples.

Comment: thank you. I was able to figure it out after dabbling with it.